# Powerpoint notes page prints with wrong font size

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint 2003 slide with a lot of text in the Notes. When I Print Preview the slide with Notes, all of the Notes text appears on the page. When I actually print the slide, the Notes are printed with a larger font, so a great deal of the text is cut off. What is the source of this discrepancy, and is there a workaround?

In general, is there a way to control the printing font size of the Notes?

Comment: What is the actual font used for Notes? Is this the default font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem with your printer not working well with the font that is used for notes. Perhaps your printer doesn't support PostScript? Try changing the font to something else (if possible) such as Arial or Times and see if there is a difference.